# Media Player Working Background process Using Service class in android

Tags: android, android-service

I Want to Create Radio Player and play in Background when i go back then play Radio. i also want to maintain stop , Pause ,next ,Previous Button . But how to play , Stop , Pause etc in Android Using Service class.

Have A Idea ??
Thanks In Advance...

Comment: You should have a look at the RandomMusicPlayer sample project which does exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you will have to bind the service with your activity.
You can follow below link to bind the service with activity.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10799514/630668

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exaple you can try...

Create a ServiceDemo.java Activity

```
 public class ServicesDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  private static final String TAG = "ServicesDemo";
  Button buttonStart, buttonStop;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting srvice");
      startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    case R.id.buttonStop:
      Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");
      stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Create a service called MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        player.start();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ServicesDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
</manifest>
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Services Demo" android:gravity="center" android:textSize="20sp" android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonStart" android:text="Start"></Button>
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Stop" android:id="@+id/buttonStop"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OP does not asking for starting and stopping a service. OP is asking for access the service on button's click.