# How to connect and communicate with service in its own process in Android

Tags: android, ipc, aidl

I am building an android music app and i have implemented player service that runs in the background with an activity that controls all the playback UI like play, pause etc.

At first the service was running in he same process. But now i have made it to run in its own process as it was blocking the UI thread while performing network IO.

Currently i am using bindservice and returning the service object to the activity.

Now how do i connect to the service and use its methods?

I know some AIDL stuff is needed, but i am new to java and android so can you show me some examples?
How do i start with AIDL

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the Android developer documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

And then consult other similar questions already answered by searching for AIDL, such as:
[Android - Using method from a Service in an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272378/android-using-method-from-a-service-in-an-activity?rq=1)